# Call php function from email

Tags: php, html-email

I have a function:

```
public function doSomething($uniqueID)
{
    $model = new model();
    $model->someFunction($uniqueID);

    $this->goSomewhere();
}
```

all it does is update a field in the database. But I'm struggling with it.
What the process of the function is, it'll create a row in the database and send an email asking to approve / decline.

I need it so, when user clicks approve / decline it goes to the doSomething function passing the ID. The href looks like "http://localhost/doSomething/uniqueID" but it fails - currently returns the view file wasn't found for it.

How can I exec a function from html email link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answer was simple :)

because the url in the email was `/controller/action?param=val` it wasn't being pulled in. Doing `/controller/action/val` is the same as doing `$fn->function($param)` :) hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You need create a link with parameter:
http://xxxxxx/pageDoSomething?uniqueID=123

And in the file execute function if parameter is ok !

**Content of pageDoSomething.php :**

```
public function doSomething($uniqueID)
{
    $model = new model();
    $model->someFunction($uniqueID);

    $this->goSomewhere();
}

if (!empty($_GET['uniqueID']) && is_int($_GET['uniqueID'])) {
   doSomething($_GET['uniqueID'])
}
```

Comment: You can post the dump of $_GET[] start at your controller ??